# Removing <U+????> like in R dataset

Tags: r

I am working on a corpus of tweets containing what I suppose to be unicode characters like `<U+0001F195>, <U+00A0>, <U+0085>, <U+0092>, <U+393C>` and more. They don't follow the same pattern, some are between sentences, some at the end while others at the beginning. Is there a way to remove all of them?

I found many similar questions, but none of them seems to work in my case, or at least not for all.
I tried using gsub and sub in tm_map like this:

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(sub), pattern = "<U+00A0>", replacement = '')
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = '<[^>]+>', replacement = ' ')
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = '<[^>]+><[^>]+>', replacement = ' ')
```